# Naming controller functions that render a form and then process the form data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In an Express.js web application, I often end up with one controller function that renders a view that provides a form for the client side to populate, and then another controller function that performs an operation given the form data.  For example, to import car data from the client, I might have the following.

In short:

- When the server receives the HTTP GET request, it responds with HTML content containing a form.
- The user clicks the submit button in the form, which sends an HTTP POST request.
- When the server receives the HTTP POST request, it performs an operation as per the form data, then responds with the result of the operation.

The URL for both the HTTP GET and the HTTP POST requests can be the same:  /car/import

But, the controller functions must be named differently.  Is there a more elegant or expected naming scheme other than just adding _get and _post to them?

myapp/routes/Router.js

```
const Express = require( 'express' );
const CarController = require( '../controllers/CarController' );

const router = module.exports = Express.Router();

router.get( '/car/import', CarController.import_get );

router.post( '/car/import', CarController.import_post );
```

myapp/controllers/CarController.js

```
/**
 * @summary Render a view to import car data and trigger the import.
 */
exports.import_get = function ( request, response, next )
{
  var data = { ... anything the view might need to initialize ... };

  // Magically fetch a views/car_import_page.ejs file.
  response.render( 'car_import_page', data );
};

/**
 * @summary Import car data.
 */
exports.import_post = async function ( request, response, next )
{
  // Form data is in request.body.

  ... perform the import ...

  // Respond with status.
  var data = 
  {
    message: 'Imported the cars successfully',
  };

  response.status( HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS.OK ).json( data );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, controller's function name **could** include the related HTTP verb (as you are already doing). Also, another common convention is about using lower or upper camel-case format.

So in your case you can consider:

```
GetCarImport
PostCarImport
```

Anyway is just about conventions and there are not strict rules.

## More infos (not directly related to your question)

What I will highlight is the usage of render functions and "REST" API's under the same service and, more important, under the same URL path naming.

This is not a standard. If you can't consider client side rendering for your project, I would suggest at least to put all of your JSON API's under some path, so that:

```
GET /car/import // reply with html content
GET /api/v1/car // reply with json content
POST /api/v1/car // reply with json content
```

You can read more [here](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/)

Comment: Thanks @radar155.  The RESTful resource naming hyperlink was interesting.  It will be a chore to avoid putting a verb in some of my URIs, though.  :)